# Rotating Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation

I am getting the blank space at the bottom when I try to rotate the relative layout... Here is my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <RelativeLayout      
          android:id="@+id/columnLayout" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="20dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"> 
         <ListView 
             android:id="@+id/columnlistview"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:background="#b0b0b0" />  
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I am trying to rotate the relative layout

```
RelativeLayout columnLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.columnLayout);
 int w = columnLayout.getWidth();
 int h = columnLayout.getHeight();
 columnLayout.setRotation(270.0f);
 columnLayout.setTranslationX((w - h)/2);
 columnLayout.setTranslationY((h - w)/2 );
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp=(ViewGroup.LayoutParams)columnLayout.getLayoutParams();
 lp.height = w; 
 lp.width = h;
 columnLayout.requestLayout();
```

Can anyone please help me how to get rid of the blank space..

TIA,
VijayRaj

Comment: Use a HorizontalScrollView instead of a rotated ListView

Comment: I have many layouts to be added dynamically....so using HorizontalScrollView will make the app slow...

Comment: why do you want to rotate it?

Comment: Check this link [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

Comment: I am trying to get horizontal list view.

Comment: its called ViewPager, isnt it?

Comment: I don't know...Anyways thanks for the idea ..I will check that :)

Comment: ViewPager doesn't fulfill my requirement... Is it possible to get horizontal list view by rotating it?

Answer (score 0):

Change height and width of listView to match_parent

Comment: Do you want to display only list in your layout ?

Comment: Yes...I am trying for a horizontal list view.

Comment: Thanks for that link...I already checked...It does not implement all the method which are available in ListView...

Comment: One more thing worth to try may be your custom layout for list items with width set to match_parent, it may be that because listView is only vertically scrollable thus listitems are getting width equal to width of devices screen width.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rotation="270" />
```